# Generate Swagger API doc from Lumen REST API

Tags: swagger, lumen, swagger-php

I have created a REST API in lumen 5.5.* now i need to create a swagger API doc for it but i Don't want to write annotations for each and every single API.

Any solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing multiple annotations (with swagger-php) you could also write a single yaml (or json) file containing all api calls.

Comment: Is there any way that i dont need to write anything in annotation like in laravel i think it is like this